# Creating an utility class with imported libraries in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, utility

(I'm new to javscript and) I want to create a utility class that has access to certain libraries on my webpage. For instance, I currently have D3 and Jquery loaded on my webpage

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="util.js"></script>
```

My utility class (utils.js) looks like

```
(function (window, JQ, D3) {

    function hasWindow(){
        console.log(window);    
    }
    function hasJquery(){
        console.log(JQ);    
    }
    function hasD3(){
        console.log(D3);    
    }
})(this, this.jQuery, this.d3);
```

I have three questions:

1. Do I need to pass in the libraries and window to use them within
   util.js, or will it already have accesss to them?
2. Once util.js is loaded, how do i call the functions on the utility class (i.e.
       hasWindow();)?
3. Am I actually using an appropriate pattern to create
       a utility class?

Comment: Your 3 `hasWindow` functions won't all exist. Function names must be unique. Try http://www.jshint.com.

Comment: @MattBall sorry, I just edited the methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing all are loaded into the page, you can access the other libraries from within your own.

It's a good idea to wait until after the page has finished loading too. You can do that in JQuery using `$(function(){ ... });`